# Get the actual table column with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm developing a calendar using Jquery selectors to obtain each cells data. When I get the data of a cell with the jquery selector I need to **obtain this cell's position** (row and column).
[image]

This is the code:

```
function fillEvent(month, year, academic_year){
            var num = 0;
            if (academic_year.includes(year)){
                var celdas = $('#calendar-body > tr > td');
                celdas.each(function(index) {
                    if ($(this).text().trim().length) {
                        var row = //obtain row
                        var column = //obtain column

                    }
                });
            } 
        }
```

```
<tbody id="calendar-body">
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
 </tr><tr>
//more code
</tbody>
```

If is needed more code I will paste it. Any suggestion?
Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1):

Just do like this,by this way you will get position of row and column

```
$('td').click(function(){
  var row_index = $(this).parent().index();
       or 
  var row_index = $(this).closest("tr").index();
  var col_index = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
});
```

Comment: The row index works but the column one is not getting the corrent value(it's getting the number of the cell, not the column number) @Ishwar Gagare